# Accessing a dynamically created set of elements in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I've made [this](https://codepen.io/fuzzylogicltd/pen/PobrqMw) in straight JS and I'm trying to implement the same sort of thing on a Gatsby site by translating it into React. Basically, the point is to have the letters appear in a random order but in their proper places.

The point at which I'm stuck (I'm pretty new to React) is how to create and access the set of elements (spans) in the randomized order to be able to get them to show in that order.

```js
class about extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            aboutText: "This is a test of the emergency broadcast system",
            aboutElements: []
        }
    }
    
    shuffleArray(array) {
        for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            var temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
        return array;
    }

    render() {

        const arrLetters = this.state.aboutText.split("");
        let arrNumbers = Array.from(Array(arrLetters.length).keys());
        arrNumbers = this.shuffleArray(arrNumbers);
        const arrSpans = arrLetters.map((letter, index) => <span key={index} id={"letter" + index}>{letter}</span>);
        console.log(arrSpans)

this.setState({ aboutElements: arrSpans })

        arrNumbers.forEach(function(item, index) {
            let targetSpan = arrSpans.filter( el => el.key == item);
// NEED TO MAKE THE LETTER VISIBLE HERE
 
        });


        return (
        <section id="about" className={styles.about}>
            <div className="container">
                <p>{ this.state.aboutElements }</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
    }
    
}

export default about
```

So what I'm creating the array of letters, turn it into an array of  elements, but the moment I try to put it into a state I get this error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate`. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `this.setState({ aboutElements: arrSpans })` inside the render method. The render function is called each time the state changes so the snake bites its tail here, creating an endless loop of render -> setState -> render -> setState -> ...

But the good news is that you can just use a local variable to render elements, without using the state:

```js
render() {

        const arrLetters = this.state.aboutText.split("");

        const arrSpans = arrLetters.map((letter, index) => <span key={index} id={"letter" + index}>{letter}</span>);
        console.log(arrSpans)

// this.setState({ aboutElements: arrSpans }) // <- not needed


        return (
        <section id="about" className={styles.about}>
            <div className="container">
                <p>{ arrSpans }</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
    }
```

I am not sure what you're planning with `arrNumbers` but i guess you could solve this issue yourself, knowing that you can just use a local variable

UPDATE:

I just made a quick sketch of the desired effect [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-shannon-h3ct3?file=/src/AnimatedLetters.js).

This is a copy of the code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function AnimatedLetters({ text }) {
  const interval = useRef();
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let count = 0;
    if (interval.current) {
      clearInterval(interval.current);
    }
    const indices = shuffleArray(
      Array.from({ length: text.length }, (_, i) => i)
    );
    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
      ++count;
      const chars = text.split("").map((char, i) => (
        <span key={i} style={{ opacity: indices[i] < count ? 1 : 0 }}>
          {char}
        </span>
      ));

      setElements(chars);
      if (count > text.length) {
        clearInterval(interval.current);
      }
    }, 100);
  }, [text]);
  return <p>{elements}</p>;
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}
```

Example usage:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("Hello Codesandbox");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AnimatedLetters text={text} />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={text}
        onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

UPDATE: now it is possible to change the text dynamically

Comment: Ah, thanks, yes that makes sens for the infinite loop. But it doesn't get me there because this is what I was doing at first, just putting the vairable in the markup, and that works. The problem with that, and the reason I started trying to do it via state is, that I need to access all those `<span>`s somehow in order to make them visible via CSS in a staggered order. The purpose os the arrNumbers is to have a randomized set of numbers in order modify the spans in a random order. My first instinct was to access the spans via DOM after they were made, but I know that's not the react way.

Comment: you can just shuffle the elements directly, as arrSpans is just an array

Comment: you could just use `{this.shuffleArray(arrSpans)}` inside your template

Comment: No, that will get me a piece of jumbled up text, which is not what I'm looking for. The letters should be in the correct order, but the order in which they appear should be random. Take a look at the link at the top of my post to see what I'm going for.

Comment: Ah now i see. What I would try: grab the element with a ref callback: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs alternatively try a css keyframe animation

Comment: You mean adda ref to each `<span>`, correct? Could you give me an example of how to go about doing that dynamically? I seem to be quite stuck with this and I can't believe it's that impossible to do.

Comment: just updated my answer with a link to an example sandbox.

Comment: Wow, that's great! Yes, you nailed it. I got frustrated and found this package https://github.com/adrianmcli/react-reveal-text in the meantime that I got to do what I was trying, but since you went through all this trouble, I'll probably go back and implement your code instead, shame for it to go to waste, and I will probably learn a thing or two that way. Thanks again!